# space between end of the div and bottom border

Tags: php, css

is there something wrong from with my code? something hidden quote i forgot to close.

```
  {
  echo '<div class="project_box" title="'. $row['title']. '">';
  echo '<p class="project_title">' . $row['title'] . '</p>';
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="200" height="200"</img>';
  echo '</div>';
  }
```

when i echo this in my project box it has some space between the bottom of the image, and the bottom border i give to the div. i give the box a height "auto".

this is the div i place the echo'ed stuff in;

```
.project_box{
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #dbae78;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

i cant find the problem:( i hope you see the problem in my code what i didn't see atm.
i want the border sticks to the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="200" height="200"</img>';
```

Should be

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '" width="200" height="200" />';
```

The `img` tag is a self closing tag, meaning it won't have a `<img>` and a `</img>`, only a `<img/>`. Also, even if it did, you still didn't have the closing bracket on the beginning of the tag.

Comment: btw, i got the image stored as a BLOB and is 43Kib. maybe is this the problem?

Comment: @user3313356 It could be, have you tested with a different image, just a jpg?

Comment: Oke, i tested with png and jpg now, even with a jpg with 100 x 100px. it dosnt change anything between the bottom of the image and the border:( 
if i make the background white and give the height 200px and dont echo the image the border sticks to the bottom. so its the image problem i think:(